# Linker error: Multiple definition of a function

Tags: c++, winapi, linker

I'm trying to write a program that includes .cpp and .h files.

Here is my code:

main.cpp:

```
#include "beep.h"
#include "movecursor.h"
```

beep.h:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

DWORD WINAPI BeepSec(LPVOID parameters);
```

beep.cpp:

```
#include "beep.h"
#include "random.h"

DWORD WINAPI BeepSec(LPVOID parameters)
{

}
```

movecursor.h:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "beep.h"

DWORD WINAPI MoveCursor(LPVOID parameters);
```

movecursor.cpp:

```
#include "movecursor.h"
#include "random.h"

DWORD WINAPI MoveCursor(LPVOID parameters)
{

}
```

random.h:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int random() {
    HCRYPTPROV prov;
    if (prov == NULL)
        if (!CryptAcquireContext(&prov, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_SILENT | CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    ExitProcess(1);

    int out;
    CryptGenRandom(prov, sizeof(out), (BYTE *)(&out));
    return out & 0x7fffffff;
}
```

But I got stuck with this linker error:

> `movecursor.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'random()' beep.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here`

Comment: `int random()` - you implement it in `random.h` and then include it to `movecursor.cpp` and `beep.cpp` - so in both this files the same `int random()` exist. you need create `random.cpp` for example and implement `int random()` here.

Comment: But using random.h will result in a compile error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple definition: error at link time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504570/multiple-definition-error-at-link-time). Also same problem: [multiple definition linker error after adding a function to a previously linking file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136616/multiple-definition-linker-error-after-adding-a-function-to-a-previously-linking)

Comment: @BDL No, not at all.

Comment: You have multiple definition of your `random` function, since multiple files include that header, which causes the linker to fail. Either put your random function in a separate cpp file, or mark it inline. Both links provided by BDL explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the definition of random() in a .cpp source file.

Use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your .h header files:

```
#ifndef RANDOM_H
#define RANDOM_H
extern int random();
...
...
#endif
```

Comment: Or mark the definition [inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).